# Attribute "name" - How to properly name this attribute?

Tags: angular, typescript

The `name` attribute is obligatory in the `ngModel`. However, I don't know what name I should give to this attribute?

By default, I always indicate `one`.

*angular*

```
<label>Nombre 1</label>
<input type="number" name="one" [(ngModel)]="number_one" /> {{ number_one }}
<br /><br />
<label>Number 2</label>
<input type="number" name="one" [(ngModel)]="number_two" /> {{ number_two }}
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Addition" (click)="addition()" /> {{ total }}
```

*typescript*

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  number_one: number = 0;
  number_two: number = 0;
  total: number = 0;

  addition(): void {
    this.total = this.number_one + this.number_two;
  }
}
```

I don't have to indicate the same value as there is on the `ngModel`?

For example:

`name="number_one" [(ngModel)]="number_one"`

Instead of:

`name="one" [(ngModel)]="number_one"` ?

Is it correct to do this?

```
<label>Nombre 1</label>
<input type="number" name="number_one" [(ngModel)]="number_one" /> {{ number_one }}
<br /><br />
<label>Number 2</label>
<input type="number" name="number_two" [(ngModel)]="number_two" /> {{ number_two }}
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Addition" (click)="addition()" /> {{ total }}
```

Comment: Outside of Angular, in pure HTML forms, the name value determines the name of the data sent in the form. Since with Angular the form is just there for display and the component or service takes care of handling the form, this seems like useless. If I were you, I'd just use the name of the variable as closely as possible, but if you are asking what you can or cannot do: You can do anything, as long as it has a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute specifies the name of an  element.

The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

The name attribute is probably the most important attribute of the  element. It isn’t strictly required for validation, but you should never omit it. When a form is submitted to the server, the data from the form is included in an HTTP request. The data is packaged as a series of name-value pairs. The name for each name-value pair is the name attribute of each input, and the value is the user-entered (or pre-specified) value. Without the name attribute, an  element cannot provide its value to the server on form submission.